How do I call Windows functions from EDK2?
I made a DXE_RUNTIME_DRIVER in EDK2. It hooks the gRT->Setvariable function, which I use to communicate with the driver from Windows (by setting a NVRAM variable, which sends data to the hooked function). I am trying to call a Windows function in memory but it never works.
I saw something similar for GNU EFI, it used __attribute__((ms_abi)) to call Windows functions. I tried to use __stdcall with the memory address of the Windows beep function. I know I have to use __stdcall somehow but I don't know what to do cause nothing worked.
